# .NET service application start slow

Tags: .net, service

I have a windows service written in c#, running on windows 7. Sometimes it will fail to start during system reboot time because it exceeded 30 seconds timeout.

I've created another simple service (created from VS 2012 template, change nothing) to test, and monitor the start time with process monitor. I found that it takes more than 20 seconds to load .NET stuff and reach my "main" function.

Anybody know any trick to speed up .NET loading during system start time?

I've tried "NGEN executequeueditems", but it does not help.
My test service has no any dependencies.

The service can be started manually very fast (within 1 seconds) after reboot time, because all .NET stuff already initialized and stay in memory.

Comment: What problem are you are trying to solve with writing this program? There may be better tools for monitoring process start times at boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try delaying your service on boot up. [This article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/delayed-start-feature-increases-options-for-windows-services/1552) gives some details.

Comment: One problem with delay start option is, the service will start very late, and our UI part will start long before our service, user has to wait for quite long time before he can operate on UI.